# Julia packages not found in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, package, julia

I'm very new to vscode and have been using previously jupyter notebooks. The problem is that when I try to run julia in vs code, it doesn't find any of the packages that have been installed with jupyter. Do I have to reinstall everything or is there some way to fix this?

The julia code works, but not the packages.

Comment: Did you install the packages in a specific Julia environment rather than the base env? Can you please precisely declare how you installed those packages?

Comment: The most likely reason, that some users reported is that, as opposed to Jupyter Notebook, which activates local environment automatically, VSCode notebook does not do this and user needs to activate it manually using the `activate` command.

Comment: I installed them using for example "import Pkg; Pkg.add("Images")". I now tried "Pkg.activate(@__DIR__)", but it still gave me this: ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Images not found in current path.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Create a project in Julia REPL and activate it**

in vs-code: install `Julia` extension, then `ctr+shift+P`, `Julia: Start Repl`

```
julia> cd("path/to/my/project/folder")
julia> pdw()
julia> ]
pkg> generate myProjectName
pkg> activate .
(myProjectName) pkg>
# hit backspace to go back to julia REPL promt
```

**2. Install a package in the active project**

You only need to do this once per package:

```
julia> ]
(myProjectName) pkg> add aPackageName
```

**3. Check files**

- `path/to/my/project/folder/Manifest.toml`
- `path/to/my/project/folder/Project.toml`

These files holds all package related infos for your project.

**4. Organize Sourcecode**

Suggestions:

- Put your `*.jl` source-files in a sub-folder, eg `./src`.
- Have one `module` per file:

```
module MyModule1
    export function1, function2

    include("./MyModule2.jl")

    const A_CONSTANT_VALUE = "fooBar"

    function function1()
        MyModule2.function3()
        ...
    end

    function function2()
    ...
    end
...
end
```