# what's the difference between modules and packages in Julia?

Tags: julia

what's the difference between modules and packages in Julia?
when developing code, when should you put your code into a module or into a package??

Comment: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages#developing-julia-packages In short a Package is a module plus the metadata to retrieve it and see with which other packages it works

Comment: See answer here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75492154/julia-packages-not-found-in-vs-code/75521459#75521459

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found:

Very simply speaking, a module is a structure that can be used to group function and struct definitions together (think namespaces). A package is a collection of one or more modules, together with various metadata (including things like a UUID and dependencies, and recorded in the Project.toml file at the root of the project folder) that can be distributed and installed using Pkg.

Thanks to Christophe Grandsire-Koevoets for the help!